# Woo commerce checkout page issue for payment gateway

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website developed by using wordpress. A payment gate was connected to it and once do integration i wasnt had time to test it. Intially it was worked. When I check today I saw that after placing an order. When we selcect the payment method as credit card and place order. It will not redirected to payment gateway website. Instead it will show thank you window.

When I check the logs. I found this. Can somebody explain me what is the issue? From which side this should be address?

```
[02-Oct-2021 09:02:12] WARNING: [pool default-one] child 30957 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: order_key was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_DirectPayV3_Gateway->process_payment, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0." 02/Oct/2021:09:02:02 +0000 "POST /index.php" 200
```

2021/10/02 09:02:12 [error] 18#18: *29690 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: order_key was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, WC_DirectPayV3_Gateway->process_payment, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 193.111.60.5, server: , request: "POST /?wc-ajax=checkout HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-default-one.sock:", host: "test.lk", referrer: "https://test.lk/checkout-2/";

Answer (score 0):

As for this error:

> order_key was called incorrectly

It means that in one of templates order_key is called directly, i.e. something like that: `$order->order_key;`.
It's not correct, use method: `$order->get_order_key();`.
But in theory, this cannot be the cause of the described problem.
I must see the template code to be more specific.